AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync uses internal browser which recognized as IE 7 by websites when called from WinForm application
My windows application  uses the AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync to get the token.
and we are using DUO security as 2FA.
Duo security requires Latest version of browser to load the authentication window. Currently it loads below error screen.
Error screen
Below is my code.
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://admin.duosecurity.com/login/", false, null);
       var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("Dummy", "Dummy2", new Uri("https://admin.duosecurity.com"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto),
           UserIdentifier.AnyUser, "scope=openid");

    }

}

Anybody faced similar issue? any solution other than Migrate confidential client applications from ADAL.NET to MSAL.NET as suggested in this link?
As My project requires changes in many places.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/how-to/migrate-confidential-client?tabs=daemon
